# What are the best practices for migrating to marketplace v2

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have an app in the Google Apps Marketplace V1 using OpenID for login and a bunch of APIs using OAuth1.0 for authentication.

Now I need to migrate it to the Google Apps Marketplace V2, so I followed the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) to update my app to use OAuth2.0 for authentication and updated all my API calls to authenticate with OAuth2.0.

Everything works fine, but now I need to switch from Marketplace V1 to Marketplace V2. The problem is that I can only have 1 version of my app live at any given time - either it uses OpenID & OAuth1.0, or it uses OAuth2.0 - it cannot use both.

So, I have 2 problems:

1. I need to submit my app for review using [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/14QOb8PbSLKDgwIp8Zv-luoAAVurPXUqtzL0Hgikp3rk/viewform). However, in order for Google to review my app in the new Marketplace, they will need the new version of my app, but I cannot push that code live, as existing customers will be disrupted - they won't even be able to log in.
2. When the new marketplace listing does go live, my app will still be running the old codebase, so any new installs wont work.

So, how do you get around this?

I currently have my marketplace listing pointing to a test environment. Question is, can I submit it for review, then change the app it points to when it's been approved? Ideally, when it does get approved it won't automatically be listed publicly in the new marketplace until I have uploaded the new code base. I guess I will then need a period of downtime in order to use the [Migration API](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2) to move my existing customers over.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll need to find a way to have two versions of the app running at the same time, both so that the new version can be reviewed, and also because migration occurs on a per-domain basis, so there will be a period of time where some customers will be on the old app and some will be on the new.